# Call helper functions in override block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to call helper function in override block

Whenever i am trying to add `__construct` in block is not loading.

Here is my code code of block

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
class Items extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items
{
    protected $_helper;
    public function __construct(
        \Company\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }
    public function callhelper(){
        $this->_helper->somefuntion();
    }
}
```

Here is my code code of helper

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function somefuntion()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy the all constructor part from `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items` & past into your custom class (extended class Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items ;`)  now add your helper class into the constructor it should work..

Comment: Unfortunately their is no `constructor` in `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Items.php` @MohammadMujassam

Comment: did you define the overriding the class in di.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first thank you for your helps. I have found way how can i call helper in override block in magento 2

In my case i have override block `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items` in my module and want to access helper function of my module.

First we need to check if their is constructor in main class i.e. `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items.php` in my case their is no constructor defined in `Items.php` so i have checked class `Items` from which it is extending and found that its extending from `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems.php` their is constructor defined i have copied that constructor in my override class i.e. `Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items.php` and set all original constructor arguments to parent constructor here is code

constructor code of `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems` class which is extended by `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items.php`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->stockConfiguration = $stockConfiguration;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

constructor code of override block i.e. `Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items.php`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Company\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct($context, $stockRegistry, $stockConfiguration, $registry, $data);
}
```

Cleared cache and generations from var folder and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your block constructor with

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Company\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
    array data = []
) {
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Since you're ultimately extending `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems` you'll need to initiate that block for everything to load properly.

Comment: Thanks Michael but unfortunately its not working whenever i have updated my code according to your suggestion i am not able to open order view getting error "Exception occurred during order load".